# Invoke-RestMethod upload a file to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file to a s3 bucket as part of existing PowerShell script, but I can't use the AWS PowerShell tools or the CLI, so I need to use `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Using this example from AWS doc:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<policy credential>,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=<my signature>"} -Uri http://<my bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com -Method Post
```

I am getting the following response:

> Invoke-RestMethod : InvalidRequestMissing required header for this
>   request: x-amz-content-sha2566

Can someone advise what am I missing?

Comment: The response is the code block you are using? Please fix your code example

Comment: sorry here is the response: Invoke-RestMethod :
InvalidRequestMissing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha2566

Comment: how to i add the value of x-amz-content-sha256? does someone have an example?

Comment: `x-amz-content-sha256` provides a hash of the request when using signature version-4 to authenticate: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonRequestHeaders.html . If I had to venture a guess, I'd say the request hash wasn't added to the header.

Comment: thanks, i managed to generate the correct signature. i am running the below curl command and trying to convert it to invoke-restMethod so i can run from powershell:  curl -X PUT -T pkg.tar.gz -H 'Host: <bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com' -H 'Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 10:22:22 -0400' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-compressed-tar' -H 'Authorization: AWS <acces key>:<signeture>' 
https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/pkg.tar.gz     what is the syntax to use? i cant get it right.. many thanks..

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/gitfvb/19826f9c04f8b9a6fede628b3682572b